# CaliburnMicro IsVisibleChanged does not fire

Tags: c#, events, caliburn.micro

The event `IsVisibleChanged` couldn't be routed to the ViewModel. What could be the cause?

If I'm testing the event as normal WPF event (no Caliburn `Message.Atach`) with CodeBehind, the Event is fired as expected. If I'm testing the Caliburn `Message.Atach` with other events of the UserControl like `LayoutUpdated`, they work like expected with the ViewModel. But I'm not able to get `IsVisibleChanged` fired to my ViewModel.

**View**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MySetupDeviceConfig.Views.SetupDeviceConfigView" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" 
         cal:Message.Attach="[Event IsVisibleChanged] = [Action UcIsVisibleChanged];">
    <Grid>
    ...
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class SetupDeviceConfigViewModel : Screen
{
    private Visibility _Visibility;
    private ILogger Log { get; set; }
    public Visibility Visibility { get => _Visibility; set { _Visibility = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(); } }

    // ...

    public void UcIsVisibleChanged()
    {
        Log.LogInformation("IsVisibleChanged");
    }
```

Tested with Caliburn.Micro v4.0.62-alpha and CaliburnMicro v3.2.0

Changing e.g. to the `Loaded` event in the view with same action/function mapping -> it works. So there is no type mismatch...

```
    cal:Message.Attach="[Event Loaded] = [Action UcIsVisibleChanged];">
```

Comment: Still an issue in 4.0.136-rc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this not working is that `IsVisibleChanged` is a CLR event and not a routed event. As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

Caliburn.Micro's Message system works on routed event not CLR events. Since Caliburn.Micro uses `EventTrigger` internally.

Why not just make a binding to `IsVisible`?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your property need to be called `IsVisible` rather than `Visibility`? Or, change the call to `NotifyOfPropertyChange` from the default to `NotifyOfPropertyChange("IsVisible")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the action on the first element (the `Grid`) inside your UserControl rather than on the UserControl itself. I tried it myself and it seemed to work on the Grid, but not on the UserControl itself, could be a Caliburn bug?

I noticed also that when I toggled the Visibility of the Grid in code-behind, the event didn't get fired, but when I bound the Visibility dependency property to a property in my ViewModel, it worked! Seems like another bug in Caliburn.

I think it's usually good practice to place events and bindings on controls inside the UserControl rather than the UserControl itself. If the UserControl gets hidden from the outside, the Grid inside it shoud fire the visibility event anyway, so it practically makes no difference.